# Singleton class can be created without using 'Static'?

Tags: swift, static, singleton

We use `Static` to declare `singleton` so only one instance will be created. Is it possible to declare singleton without using `Static`? If yes, can the instance be overridden?

```
class SingletonClass {
    static let shared = SingletonClass();
    func requestToAccess() {
        // Print statement
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: Without keyword `static` your property `shared` will become `instance` property, i.e. linked to some `instance`. So you would need to have `instance` to refer to the `instance`. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here, so let's clear those up first:

1. This is invalid Swift code. `Class` and `Static` both have to be lower cased.
2. Type names in Swift should be UpperCamelCase.
3. The formatting is all wonky.

Fixing that, we get:

```
class SingletonClass {
    static let shared = SingletonClass()

    func requestToAccess() {
        print(SingletonClass.shared)
    }
}
```

What you have here is a shared instance, but not actually a singleton. The key defining characteristic of a singleton is that it's well ... single. That is not at all the case here, because absolutely nothing is stopping me from saying:

```
let myOwnInstance = SingletonClass()
```

Singletons are typically used to model state of a singular physical resource. If two instances exist, they can interfere with each other. Consider this example, of a (flawed) singleton that attempts to model a single LED on a piece of hardware:

```
public class UserActivityIndicatorLED {
    public static let shared = UserActivityIndicatorLED()

    public private(set) var currentState: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if currentState { turnLEDOn() }
            else { turnLEDOff() }
        }
    }

    public func toggle() { self.currentState.toggle() }
}
```

It is not uncommon for "write-only" things to exist, where you have an API for setting a value (such as the on/off state of a digital output pin of a micro controller), but no corresponding API for checking the state. Under such a circumstance, your program needs to remember the state by saving it to a variable, and ensuring the "remembered state" and the real hardware are always updated together.

This implementation ensures that's done correctly, because `turnLEDOn` and `turnLEDOff` can only be called by mutating currentState. However, since the singleton property is violated, this can happen:

```
UserActivityIndicatorLED.shared().toggle() // => UserActivityIndicatorLED.shared().currentState becomes true, LED turns on

let myInstance = UserActivityIndicatorLED() // => I create a new instance, violating the singleton pattern
myInstance.toggle() // myInstance.currentState becomes true, LED is made to turn on again (it just stays on)
myInstance.toggle() // myInstance.currentState becomes false, LED is turned off, but UserActivityIndicatorLED.shared().currentState is still true!


// Now the system's "memory" of the physical state is desynchronized from the
// "true hardware" state, because creating a new instance of `UserActivityIndicatorLED`
// permitting the mutation of the hardware state without a corresponding update to the
// memorized state.
// Some user calls this again, expecting the LED to turn off, but surprise, it's already off!
UserActivityIndicatorLED.shared().toggle() // UserActivityIndicatorLED.shared().currentState becomes false, but the light was already off
```

To fix this, and to ensure you *actually* have a singleton, the initializer need to be made private, so that new instances can only be made within `SingletonClass`, and so that the only call to the initializer is for the `shared` variable:

```
class SingletonClass {
    static let shared = SingletonClass()

    private init() { }

    func requestToAccess() {
        print(SingletonClass.shared)
    }
}
```

## Do I need to use a static variable?

Not necessarily, you *could* use global variable, but that's worse:

```
let SingletonClassShared = SingletonClass()

class SingletonClass {
    fileprivate init() { }

    func requestToAccess() {
        print(SingletonClass.shared)
    }
}
```

But you do you need some form of static storage (global variable, static storage, class storage). Instance storage (stored properties) don't actually allocate memory unless there's an instance. And since there is no instance to store the singleton reference in, it doesn't really make sense.